# XLRDError: No sheet named <'Sheet1'> in python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to convert the xls into csv file using pandas in python. But I am getting the following error like 'XLRDError: No sheet named <'Sheet1'>'. I have verified the sheet name and it is same as specified above, but I don't how to correct this error. Please find my code below.

CODE:

```
 def xls_2_csv():

 import pandas as pd
 data_xls = pd.read_excel(r'c:\delivery\file1.xls','Sheet1', index_col=None)
 data_xls.to_csv(r'C:\test\file1.csv', encoding='utf-8',index=None)

 xls_2_csv()
```

Please help me in solving this error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is multiple sheets? If only one, you can omit `Sheet1` - `data_xls = pd.read_excel(r'c:\delivery\file1.xls', index_col=None)`

Comment: What version of pandas use? `print pd.show_versions()`

Comment: @jezrael: Thanks for the reply, I am using pandas: 0.14.1 .I am having only one sheet and I am getting the following error if I remove the sheet name    " *** No CODEPAGE record, no encoding_override: will use 'ascii' ".

Comment: I think you can update pandas, because for me it works very well. The last version of `pandas` is `0.18.0`. alternativly try remove `Sheet`

Comment: @jezrael: I tried to update pandas 18.0, but got the error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat . I tried reinstalling visual studio but it did not work for me.

Comment: If I create answer with comment, can you accept me?

Comment: @jazrael: Thanks for the reply, but in the previous comment, I did not complete it fully.

Answer (score 2):

I found the same problem in python 3.6 and pandas version is 0.25.1.

The following should work:

```
import pandas as pd
file = 'your excel file path'
# the file is endswith '.xls' and there is multiple sheets

# error method
df_sheet1 = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='Sheet1')
df_sheet2 = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name='Sheet2')
# when read Sheet1 had no error, but when read Sheet2, had an error: 
# xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: No sheet named <'Sheet2'>


# right method 
with pd.ExcelFile(file) as xls:
    for sheet_name in xls.sheet_names:
        df = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name=sheet_name)
        print(df.head())
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I tried the following code it worked for me.

CODE:

```
import logging
import time
import traceback
import xlrd
import csv
import sys
import re

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')

xls = input file path
target = output file path

logging.info("Start converting: From '" + xls + "' to '" + target + "'. ")

try:
    start_time = time.time()
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(xls)
    sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

    csvFile = open(target, 'wb')
    wr = csv.writer(csvFile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for row in xrange(sh.nrows):
        rowValues = sh.row_values(row)

        newValues = []
        for s in rowValues:
            if isinstance(s, unicode):
                strValue = (str(s.encode("utf-8")))
            else:
                strValue = (str(s))

            isInt = bool(re.match("^([0-9]+)\.0$", strValue))

            if isInt:
                strValue = int(float(strValue))
            else:
                isFloat = bool(re.match("^([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)$", strValue))
                isLong  = bool(re.match("^([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)e\+([0-9]+)$", strValue))

                if isFloat:
                    strValue = float(strValue)

                if isLong:
                    strValue = int(float(strValue))

            newValues.append(strValue)

        wr.writerow(newValues)

    csvFile.close()

    logging.info("Finished in %s seconds", time.time() - start_time)

except Exception as e:
    print (str(e) + " " +  traceback.format_exc())
```